# Using apache common exec to write to pdf

Tags: java, apache-commons

HI all i am trying to use this apache common exec, using this i am trying to create and write to a file.
the command line argument to write to a file is follows
Example: PDFAnnotator.exe "C:\My Documents\Test.pdf"
I have tried the following

```
public PrintResultHandler print(final File file, final long printJobTimeout, final boolean printInBackground)
            throws IOException {

        int exitValue;
        ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = null;
        PrintResultHandler resultHandler;

        // build up the command line to using a 'java.io.File'
        CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 11.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe");
        //CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("file", new File("C:\\test\\invoice.pdf"));
        commandLine.addArgument("/p");
        commandLine.addArgument("/h");
        commandLine.addArgument("${file}");

        // create the executor and consider the exitValue '1' as success
        final Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.setExitValue(1);

        // create a watchdog if requested
        if (printJobTimeout > 0) {
            watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(printJobTimeout);
            executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
        }

        // pass a "ExecuteResultHandler" when doing background printing
        if (printInBackground) {
            System.out.println("[print] Executing non-blocking print job  ...");
            resultHandler = new PrintResultHandler(watchdog);
            executor.execute(commandLine, (Map<String, String>) resultHandler);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("[print] Executing blocking print job  ...");
            exitValue = executor.execute(commandLine);
            resultHandler = new PrintResultHandler(exitValue);
        }

        return resultHandler;
    }
```

it does not create any pdf file as an output can you please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this code has been modified from the [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/xref-test/org/apache/commons/exec/TutorialTest.html) tutorial code.  There are a couple of modifications to the code it seems you have made which have caused problems.

Firstly, you have deleted the line

```java
      commandLine.setSubstitutionMap(map);
```

Without this line, you are creating the variable `map`, putting a single value into this map and then doing nothing further with it.  Clearly, having a map that you never read any values out of achieves nothing.  Reinstate this line, it's important.

The other problem is the line

```java
            executor.execute(commandLine, (Map<String, String>) resultHandler);
```

The difference between this code and the tutorial code is that you have added the cast to `Map<String, String>`.  `resultHandler` is a `PrintResultHandler`, but this class does not implement `Map<String, String>` so this cast will fail.

I don't see why you have the cast at all.  Get rid of it to leave you with:

```java
            executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
```

If your code continues not to work, then I can't say what the reasons would be.  Maybe the Adode Reader executable isn't where you think it is, maybe the file doesn't exist or doesn't have read permissions.  In any case, suitable details should be written to standard output or standard error to help you further diagnose the problem.